# React failed to read config from .env

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on ReactJS and trying to read some configs from .env file.
I follow instruction from this [page](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) but it doesn't work for me.

Here is my Test.js:

```
import React from 'react';
require('dotenv').config()


class Test extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state={
            user:process.env.DB_USER,
            pass:process.env.DB_PASS
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Test</p>
                {this.state.user}
                {this.state.pass}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Test;
```

Here is my .env file:

```
DB_USER=test
DB_PASS=test
```

Here is my folder structure:

[image]

On my page I get only the text: "Test". So I think the app cannot get the value from .env file.

[image]

Is there anyone here can help me to read configs from .env file? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: what is logged to the terminal/console when you add this? `console.log( require('dotenv').config() )`

Comment: @DacreDenny VM98:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:9
Am I missing something?

Comment: If you are using create-react-app, there is a [build in mechanism](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables) for adding env variables

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings hi mate, I also read this page but I get an error on the line "process.env.user": process is not defined

Comment: A password seems like something that you don't want to store in your react application.  It will be visible for anyone to use.

Comment: @SteveK it's just a test to read from config file

Comment: @anhtv13 it has to have `REACT_APP` as the prefix for create-react-app

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you use create-react-app for your project boilerplate. You can just add REACT_APP prefix to your env variables. First, create a .env file at your root directory (outside src folder). In your .env file

```
REACT_APP_USERNAME=lorem
```

then you can call it anywhere in your project by using process.env.REACT_APP_USERNAME, for example

```
console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_USERNAME)
```

I hope this works and good luck

Answer (score 1):

***1) [ReactDocs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables) If you use create-react-app as boilerplate***

**1.1 #.env file**

```
REACT_APP_SOME_NAME=something
```

**Name MUST start with REACT_APP_**

**1.2 Access ENV variable**

```
<p>{process.env.REACT_APP_SOME_NAME}</p>
```

**1.3 npm run start**

Restart application after adding variable in .env file using `npm run start`

***2) If not using `create-react-app`***

**2.1)** `npm install dotenv --save`

**2.2)** Next add the following line to your app.

`require('dotenv').config()`

**2.3)** Then create a .env file at the root directory of your application and add the variables to it and restart application after adding variables using `npm start`.

`// contents of .env`

`REACT_APP_API_KEY = 'my-secret-api-key'`

**2.4)** Finally, add `.env` to your `.gitignore` file so that Git ignores it and it never ends up on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're running your app from the root directory of the project, my understanding is that you'll need to specify the path of the `.env` file as `src` like this:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

/* Specify path to .env file */
dotenv.config({ path: 'src' });
```

Comment: It doesn't work mate. I set a debugger in constructor and it shows that "process is not defined". Dont know why :(

Comment: Quick question - the `dotenv` package has been installed right?

Comment: Thanks for confirming that. If you do this, is anything logged?

`const result = dotenv.config({ path: 'src' }); console.log("Err", result.error);`

Comment: did you import the dotenv at the beginning of the file?